# Can't install due to pusher package is lock

Tags: php, laravel

I try to install a package on my project. When it updates the dependencies it produces 2 problems

> Problem 1

- pusher/pusher-php-server is locked to version v3.4.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
- pusher/pusher-php-server v3.4.1 requires php >=5.4 <7.4 -> your php version (7.4.15) does not satisfy that requirement.

> Problem 2

- pusher/pusher-php-server v3.4.1 requires php >=5.4 <7.4 -> your php version (7.4.15) does not satisfy that requirement.
- beyondcode/laravel-websockets 1.9.0 requires pusher/pusher-php-server ^3.0|^4.0 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[v3.4.1].
- beyondcode/laravel-websockets is locked to version 1.9.0 and an update of this package was not requested.

What kind of problem is this? And how do I solve these errors

Comment: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php/issues/249 Upgrade pusher or downgrade PHP. I would suggest upgrading pusher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Sammitch says, your current package version doesn't support PHP 7.4.

Pusher support PHP 7.4 since `4.1.1`, so upgrade you pusher to `4.1.1` or above by changing your `composer.json` to:

```
"pusher/pusher-php-server": "4.1.1",
```

Based on changelog, I think no breaking change from v3.4.1 to v4.1.1 but alternatively if you want to use 3.4.1 just downgrade your PHP to 7.3